# Error message in docker about user specified subnet

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm trying to attribute an IP for a container using the `--ip` flag. But I get the following message:

`Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets.`

What does this message mean? How do I get the container to run?

The network was created with the command:
`docker network create my_network_name`

And the container is called with:
`docker run -it --net my_network_name --ip 172.22.0.30 image_name`

Comment: The error message means that you also need to specify a CIDR block when creating the network.  But the Docker-internal IP addresses are usually just implementation details, and they're unusable in many common circumstances; I'd just delete the `--ip` option and use the automatically assigned address.

Comment: Docker threw that error even when I had the network created with right subnet. Restarting docker fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

When you create your network provide a subnet from the [private IP range](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) that is free in your network. Then when you create your container in this network pick an address from that subnet.

For instance with IP range 10.11.0.0/16 and container IP 10.11.0.10:

```
$ docker network create my_network_name --subnet=10.11.0.0/16
$ docker run -it --net my_network_name --ip 10.11.0.10 image_name
```

And here is an actual run:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
$ uname -a
Linux 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ docker network create my_network_name --subnet=10.11.0.0/16
35a9e4e5fb4ff243202fc4f6b687901c3cbfcd8fe34e06290db5d257310417a2
$ docker run --rm -it --net my_network_name --ip 10.11.0.10 ubuntu
root@f0d283bc5023:/#
```

On another window:

```
$ docker network inspect my_network_name
[
    {
        "Name": "my_network_name",
        "Id": "35a9e4e5fb4ff243202fc4f6b687901c3cbfcd8fe34e06290db5d257310417a2",
        "Created": "2020-09-19T11:51:59.985580503-07:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.11.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "f0d283bc5023fbe8a1c854fd2bb5bdd121be7245013cfac62d9933f95ace7bbf": {
                "Name": "sleepy_colden",
                "EndpointID": "088fbd64b82e05920fda91b28ebb5b4a14c9fca3ac9fde457c8819663f6049df",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0b:00:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "10.11.0.10/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```